# Trying to get eigenvalues for the system of equations with sympy and get ': AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'arctan2''

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to get eigenvalues' real parts for the equation system in its stationary points

Here is the code:

```
    #  equation system

x0, y0, e_x, d_x, d_y, e_y, K, t = sym.symbols('x0, y0, e_x, d_x, d_y, e_y, K, t')
x = sym.Function('x')(t)
y = sym.Function('y')(t)

x_rate = e_x * x - d_x * x * y + K/ x
y_rate = d_y * x * y - e_y * y

eq1 = sym.Eq(x.diff(t), x_rate)
eq2 = sym.Eq(y.diff(t), y_rate)

# parameters
# e_x_, e_y_, d_x_, d_y_,  K
e_x0 = 0.4
e_y0 = 1
d_x0 = 0.4
d_y0 = 1
K0 = 0.00000001

# jacobian
J = sym.Matrix([x_rate, y_rate]).jacobian(sym.Matrix([x,y]))

# eigen vectors
J_vects = J.eigenvects()

# stationary points
roots = sym.nonlinsolve([eq1.rhs.subs({e_x:e_x0, d_x:d_x0, K:K0}), 
                        eq2.rhs.subs({e_y:e_y0, d_y:d_y0})], 
                        [x, y])
roots_list =  [(x, y) for x, y in roots.args]

# eigen values


f_eigen1 = sym.lambdify([x, y, e_x, e_y, d_x, d_y, K], sym.re(J_vects[0][0]))
f_eigen2 = sym.lambdify([x, y, e_x, e_y, d_x, d_y, K], sym.re(J_vects[1][0]))

f_eigen1(roots_list[0][0], roots_list[0][1],  e_x0, d_x0, e_y0, d_y0, K0)
```

And  i get an error in the last string:
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'arctan2'

I can't understand which library tries to find  an artcan2 attribute for the float values.
And if i won't turn them into floats,  the lambdified function won't be able to deal with them?

UPD: the problem was in the line

```
roots_list =  [(x, y) for x, y in roots.args]
```

values in the list had the type sympy.core.numbers.Float

When i run

```
roots_list =  [(float(sym.re(x)), float(sym.re(y))) for x, y in roots.args]
```

the error disapperars.

But. Now  i realise that i don't clearly mathematically  understand how to deal with this roots with imaginary parts - without 'i' they just turn into zeros...
Now i can get eigen values for at least the first pair of roots, and can analyse its stability, but what about other two pairs?

Comment: Though `J_vects[0][0]` doesn't contain `arctan`, `sym.re(J_vectors[0][0])` does, and that's where the `arctan` is coming from.  I don't quite understand what your code is doing, so I'm not sure if that's reasonable or not.

Comment: Look at `help(f_eigen1)`.  Does that contain `arctan` calls?  Are you passing any sympy objects (symbols or expressions to `f_eigen1`?  You'll get this kind of error if `np.arctan2(arr1,arr2)` is called with an `object` dtype array.  `np.arctan2` only works if given numeric dtype arrays.

Comment: You don't even have to look at the `help`.  Simply look at the FULL error message.  The `arctan2` expression will be highlighted (at least it is in my QtConsole run).  The sympy expression is long, and the lambdified code equally so.  Lots of `real/imag(_Dummy...)` calls.

Comment: @hpaulj Interestingly, running from the standard command line interpreter, I simply see no code shown for the final level of the stack trace. I've honestly never seen that before.

Comment: I wonder if you could evaluate `sym.re(J_vects[0][0])` at specific numeric values (with `feval`, `subs`), without going through the `numpy` `lambdify`.

Comment: @Diana I rolled back your edit. Please don't add solutions to questions; you can post (and even accept!) an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I specify 'sympy' as the lambdifing language, rather than the default `numpy`, I get:

```
In [19]: f_eigen1 = sym.lambdify([x, y, e_x, d_x, K], sym.re(J_vects[0][0]),['sympy'])

In [20]: f_eigen1(roots_list[0][0], roots_list[0][1], e_x0, d_x0, K0)
Out[20]: 
-0.707106781186548*((re(d_y)*im(d_y) + re(e_y)*im(e_y) - 0.8*im(d_y) - 0.000200000000000033*im(e_y) - im(d_y*e_y))**2 + (0.5*re(d_y)**2 - 0.8*re(d_y) + 0.5*re(e_y)**2 - 0.000200000000000033*re(e_y) - re(d_y*e_y) - 0.5*im(d_y)**2 - 0.5*im(e_y)**2 + 2.00000000172285e-8)**2)**0.25*cos(0.5*atan2(2.0*re(d_y)*im(d_y) + 2.0*re(e_y)*im(e_y) - 1.6*im(d_y) - 0.000400000000000067*im(e_y) - 2.0*im(d_y*e_y), 1.0*re(d_y)**2 - 1.6*re(d_y) + 1.0*re(e_y)**2 - 0.000400000000000067*re(e_y) - 2.0*re(d_y*e_y) - 1.0*im(d_y)**2 - 1.0*im(e_y)**2 + 4.00000000344569e-8)) + 0.5*re(d_y) - 0.5*re(e_y) - 0.000100000000000017
```

I don't know if that's useful, but it does tell me that `d_y` and `e_y` are still symbols.  Leaving symbols in a `numpy` `lamdified` function is bound to give errors like this.

```
In [22]: np.arctan2(d_y,e_y)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[22], line 1
----> 1 np.arctan2(d_y,e_y)

AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'arctan2'

In [24]: np.arctan2(1.0,e_y)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[24], line 1
----> 1 np.arctan2(1.0,e_y)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'arctan2'

In [25]: np.arctan2(1.0,2)
Out[25]: 0.4636476090008061
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, i realised that both eigen values formulas utilise all the variables, which i didn't provide in lambdify, that was one of the problems